# What's the alternative to using a StreamBuilder inside of a column or row?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a page that shows a hierarchy of data. The top of the page is built by passed in data. But the dependencies need to query a db and post their results.

For example Team A has players. Under the heading of team A I want to show a list of players on the team. But if I try to add a streamBuilder as a part of screen, I get all sorts of nasty message about some part of the build process not having a height. Its seems that streamBuilder only works as the highest level widget.

So there must be an alternative for building those widgets, can anyone point me to an example of that being used?

Comment: StreamBuilder works inside columns/rows. It's most likely what you build inside it that doesn't work.

Comment: I experimented with a working stream, just the act of putting it inside of a Column caused it to break.

Comment: Putting it in a container seems to work, but putting it in a column gives me this error: 
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (19066): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Comment: In SO, whenever you can, send an actual runnable code to reproduce the error. Saying "It doesn't work" don't help.

Comment: I agree with Darky, I'd love to tinker with this and see of we can help ya out

Comment: Yes, please include code. But this 99% sounds like problem with something other than streambuilder - like the list you're making with the streambuilder. Try making a list with static data and see what happens.
I'd guess what's happening is that you have something that scrolls (i.e. listview) within something else that scrolls; when flutter tries laying them out it can't decide what sizes to give them. But anyways, once you post code we can help =) !

Comment: Seeing the error from the comment `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`, I guess that you are trying to use a `ListView`/`GridView` inside a `Column`. There are some workaround to this like, wrapping it in `Expanded`, wrapping in `SizedBox` and give a bounded `height` or use `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView`/`GridView`. If this is not the case, you can help the community check for the issue by providing [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a StreamBuilder is [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) - where you can use a Future callback instead of a Stream to fetch a data snapshot for the children Widgets inside it.

However, if you're getting "unbounded height" errors, this is usually thrown by children Widgets with undefined height inside a ListView or Scrollable widget. You'll be needing to set a height for those List items to fix that error.